# DataTables with different number of columns

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, datatables

I am loading data using ajax and generating column names dynamically in my DataTable. My DataTable has different number of columns, depending on the selection by user.(There is a drop-down list).

For example, there are 2 options in drop-down list as **Southern Province** and **Northern Province**. **Southern Province** table has 4 columns and **Northern Province** table has 6 columns.

**Scenario 1**

First user select **Southern Province** which has 4 columns. Then it generates table without no errors, But after that if user select **Northern Province** which has 6 columns, table not generate and js console print error as below.

`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of undefined jquery.dataTables.js:3828`

**Scenario 2**

First user select **Northern Province** which has 6 columns. Then it generates table without no errors, But after that if user select **Southern Province** which has 4 columns, table not generate and js console print error as below.

`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'mData' of undefined jquery.dataTables.js:6122`

But if both table has same number of columns, both tables generate without errors.

How can I solve this ?

**Here is the JS Code**

```
jQuery(document)
.ready(
function() {
    $('#province-list').change(
            function() {
                var prov = $(this).val();
                if (prov == "sp") {
                    make_SP();
                } else if (prov == "np") {
                    make_NP();
                }
            });
    function make_SP() {
    $("#dataTables-res_item")
    .dataTable(
    {
        "bDestroy" : true,
        "bProcessing" : false,
        "bServerSide" : true,
        "sAjaxSource" : "/province_list_view?p_name=sp",
        "aoColumns" : [
                {
                    "mData" : "result_date",
                    "sTitle" : "Result Date"
                },
                {
                    "mData" : "result_day",
                    "sTitle" : "Result Day"
                },
                {
                    "mData" : "draw_number",
                    "sTitle" : "Draw Number"
                },
                {
                    "mData" : "draw_time",
                    "sTitle" : "Draw Time"
                } ],
        "order" : [ [ 0, "desc" ] ]
        });
    };                  
    function make_NP() {
        $("#dataTables-res_item")
        .dataTable(
        {
            "bDestroy" : true,
            "bProcessing" : false,
            "bServerSide" : true,
            "sAjaxSource" : "/province_list_view?p_name=np",
            "aoColumns" : [
                    {
                        "mData" : "result_date",
                        "sTitle" : "Result Date"
                    },
                    {
                        "mData" : "result_day",
                        "sTitle" : "Result Day"
                    },
                    {
                        "mData" : "draw_number",
                        "sTitle" : "Draw Number"
                    },
                    {
                        "mData" : "draw_time",
                        "sTitle" : "Draw Time"
                    },
                    {
                        "mData" : "draw_place",
                        "sTitle" : "Draw Place"
                    },
                    {
                        "mData" : "draw_person",
                        "sTitle" : "Agent"
                    } ],
            "order" : [ [ 0, "desc" ] ]
        });
    };
});
```

Comment: Make working fiddle and let us know

Comment: Try this once, before calling make_SP() function destroy the datatable.

Comment: @Gowri How can i do that ? I used `"bDestroy" : true`. but it not worked.

Comment: @Bishan In general, to destroy table
`var table = $('#tabid').DataTable();
table.destroy();`

Comment: @Gowri Tried your solution and got js error as `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'aDataSort' of undefined jquery.dataTables.js:4160`

Comment: Is your table have thead & tbody tags.

Comment: @Gowri I have only this. `<table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover"
         id="dataTables-res_item">
        </table>`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/63390/discussion-between-gowri-and-bishan).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I think the safest way is to remove the table completely, and then re-insert it to the DOM before reinitialising. Seems to me that dataTables not completely removes all generated content, thats why the error(s) occurs (for different reasons). In theory it should work as above, more or less, but it doesn't. Consider this solution :

[full source in the demo link below]

```js
var dataTable,
    domTable, 
    htmlTable = '<table id="example"><tbody></tbody></table>';

function initDataTable(province) {
    if ($.fn.DataTable.fnIsDataTable(domTable)) {
        dataTable.fnDestroy(true);
        $('body').append(htmlTable);
    } 
    var data = (province=='sp') ? sp : np;
    var columns = (province=='sp') ? spColumns : npColumns;    
    dataTable = $("#example").dataTable({
        aaData : data,
        aoColumns : columns
        /* other options here */
    });        
    domTable = document.getElementById('example');
}

$('#province-list').change(function() {
    var prov = $(this).val();
    initDataTable(prov);
});
```

This works. See demo -> **http://jsfiddle.net/gss4a17t/** 
Basically it is the same as in OP, but instead of having different functions for different provinces, I have made different `aoColumns` for different provinces and so on. And instead of relying on `bDestroy`, I remove the entire `<table>` with `dataTable.fnDestroy(true)` (both DOM *and* and dataTables injections) and then reinserts the `<table>`-skeleton before reinitialising the dataTable.

I dont know if that is adaptable to OP's need, but this is how I would do it. It is more flexible for future changes, and the `aoColumns`-objects can be autogenerated from a script or achieved from the server by AJAX (if you want to have different titles for different languages, for example). "Belt and braces" :)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have little question. I am getting data by calling url. How can i use it with `aaData` ?

Comment: hey @Bishan, and thank you for upvoting! :) I think it should be the same, you get data from the server in the same JSON format as in the fiddle I guess?  Then you get the data, insert the result as `aaData`. So call "initDataTable" or whatever you name it, in the success handler of your AJAX. I cannot reproduce this in a fiddle, but this should be the case.

Comment: Thanks @davidkonrad, I used `sAjaxSource` instead of `aaData`. Now it's working. :)

Answer (score 15):

I faced the same issue when my updated data had **different number of columns** than the previous data. The recipe is really **simple!** In the scenario when there is a **change in number of columns**, `Destroy function` works in conjunction with `$("#datatable").empty();`. So before reloading data your code would contain following lines:

```
if (dataTableObject) { // Check if DataTable has been previously created and therefore needs to be flushed

    dataTableObject.fnDestroy(); // destroy the dataTableObject
    // For new version use table.destroy();
    $('#' + DataTableDivID).empty(); // Empty the DOM element which contained DataTable
    // The line above is needed if number of columns change in the Data
    }
// DataTable data loading/reloading codes comes here
```

So overall, your code may look like this:

```
if(dataTableObject) { // Check if table object exists and needs to be flushed
    dataTableObject.fnDestroy(); // For new version use table.destroy();
    $('#myTable').empty(); // empty in case the columns change
}

var data = (province=='sp') ? sp : np;
var columns = (province=='sp') ? spColumns : npColumns;

dataTableObject = $('#myTable').DataTable({
        columns: columns,
        data:    data
    });
```

Comment: I have posted your solution as a comment to https://datatables.net/manual/tech-notes/3#destroy.  (Still pending moderation right now).

Comment: My solution working on this just now for one of my projects was very similar to this, except I couldn't get the check on if it was a datatable working, so I wrapped it in `<div id='tablewrapper'>` and checked `if (table.parent().attr('id') != 'tablewrapper')`. The benefit of this method is it's not dependent on the function name in the version of datatables being used.

Answer (score 0):

There is good solution up there but after ran into this question, dynamism still ring the bell on my mind. i would like to share this , not a export in js. So please comment.

```
function genericAjaxCall(url, tableId, _header, _dataMapping, isData,
    isEditDelete) {
if (!isData) {
    $.ajax({
        url : url,
        method : "GET",
        dataType : "JSON",
        success : function(data) {
            var editDeletUrl = url.split("/");
            var dataArray = createArray(_header, data, _dataMapping, url,
                    isEditDelete)
            createListHeading(tableId, dataArray, false);
            initDT(tableId, dataArray);
        },
        error : function(xhr) {
            console.log(xhr);
            openErrorModal("Guru", xhr.responseText);
        }
    });
} else {
    var dataArray = createArray(_header, url, _dataMapping);
    console.log(dataArray);
    var finalData = dataArray + objName;
    console.log(finalData);
    createListHeading(tableId, dataArray, false);
    initDT(tableId, dataArray);
 }
}

function createArrayWithDelete(_header, data, _dataMapping, url) {
var posts = {};
posts.postDT = []
for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    var jsonData = {};

    for (var j = 0; j < _header.length; j++) {
        if (_dataMapping[j].indexOf('.') !== -1) {
            var parts = _dataMapping[j].split(".");
            if (String(data[i][parts[0]][parts[1]]).indexOf('*') !== -1) {
                jsonData[_header[j]] = data[i][parts[0]][parts[1]].bold()
                        .replace("*", "");
            } else {
                jsonData[_header[j]] = data[i][parts[0]][parts[1]];
            }

        } else {

            if (String(data[i][_dataMapping[j]]).indexOf('*') !== -1) {
                jsonData[_header[j]] = data[i][_dataMapping[j]].bold()
                        .replace("*", "");
            } else {
                jsonData[_header[j]] = data[i][_dataMapping[j]];
            }
        }
    }

    if (_header[_header.length - 1]) {
        jsonData["Action"] = deleteOnly(url,
                data[i][_dataMapping[_dataMapping.length - 1]]);
    }

    posts.postDT.push(jsonData);
   }
   return posts.postDT;
  }

function createListHeading(tableId, data, isAction) {
var posts = {
    post : []
};
$.each(data[0], function(key, value) {
    posts.post.push({
        "mDataProp" : key,
        "sTitle" : key
        /* "sType" : "string" */
    });
   });
  cols = posts.post

 }

function initDT(tableId, results) {
// Construct the measurement table
data_table = $('#' + tableId).DataTable({
    "iDisplayLength" : 10,
    scrollCollapse : true,
    "aaSorting" : [],
    "aaData" : results,
    "aoColumns" : cols
});
$('#' + tableId).DataTable().columns.adjust();
}
```

And this is how i call ,

```
$(function() {
    var header = [ "H1", "H2", "H3", "H4" ];
    var dataMapping = [ "d1", "d2", "d3", "d3" ];

    genericAjaxCall("ajaxurlWhichreturnJSON", "tableId", header, dataMapping,
            false, true);
});
```

Here d1, d2... are the key of your ajax response. Now we do not need to worry that which value user select. Note : this is not direct solution of this question but it is figurative

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question, but since I spent several hours trying to solve it with DataTables 1.10.18, I publish it with the hope that it will help someone. I used JavaScript arrays as data source, and jQuery 1.12.4. It is based on @davidkonrad's answer.

HTML:

```
select province
<select id="province-list">
  <option value="sp">sp</option>
  <option value="np">np</option>    
</select>    
<br><br>

<div id="table-container">
    <table id="example" class="display"></table>
</div>
```

JS:

```
var sp = [
  [ 'col1', 'col2'] ,
  [ 'col11', 'col22']    
];

var np = [
  [ 'col1', 'col2', 'col3', 'col4' ],
  [ 'col11', 'col22', 'col33', 'col44' ]
];

var spColumns = [
  { title : "column1" },
  { title : "column2" }
];

var npColumns = [
  { title : "column1" },
  { title : "column2" },
  { title : "column3" },
  { title : "column4" }      
];

var dataTable,
  htmlTable = '<table id="example" class="display"></table>';

function initDataTable(province) {
  if ($.fn.DataTable.isDataTable('#example')) {
    dataTable = $('#example').DataTable();
    dataTable.destroy(true);
    $('#table-container').empty();
    $('#table-container').append(htmlTable);
  } 
  var data = (province=='sp') ? sp : np;
  var columns = (province=='sp') ? spColumns : npColumns;  

  dataTable = $('#example').DataTable( {
    "data": data,
    "columns": columns
  } );
}

$(document).ready(function() {
  initDataTable('sp');

  $('#province-list').change(function() {
    var prov = $(this).val();
    initDataTable(prov);
  });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  if(table) {
                table.destroy(); //destroy tableData object
                $('#dttable').empty(); //clear table
            }
   table = $('#dttable').DataTable({
                columns: cols, //set  new columns array
                data:    data1 //set new data
            });
```