# How to deactivate table sorting in datatables.js in this example

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

Adapting the following SO question [DataTables with different number of columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26480434/datatables-with-different-number-of-columns)
and the referring solution (gss4a17t) :

I want to deactivate the sort feature of datatables.js.

I tried to put it at the position visible here: http://jsfiddle.net/koerner_klaus/csou71bn/5/

Unfortunately, I get an error message during debugging:

> DataTables warning: table id=example - Cannot reinitialise DataTable. For more information about this error, please see http://datatables.net/tn/3

Where do I have to put

```
$('#example').dataTable( {
  "ordering": false
} );
```

so that it works?

Comment: In the first call to `.dataTable()`, like this: http://jsfiddle.net/csou71bn/6/

Comment: This works! Perfect

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried something like this?

```
$('#example').dataTable( {
    "order": [],
    "columnDefs": [ {
      "targets"  : 'no-sort',
      "orderable": false,
    }]
});
```

If that didn't work, you can try this too

```
$(document).ready( function () {$('#example').dataTable( {
    "bSort": false
  } );
}
```

If you want to deactivate initial sort, please try this

```
$(document).ready( function() {
  $('#example').dataTable({
    "aaSorting": []
});
})
```

Comment: the first solution does not have any data in the table.

how would I do the solutions 2 and 3 in jsFiddle?

Comment: Please add the data and try once. Thanks

Comment: it works already with the solution of @Hanlet Escaño 

. 
Therefore I got already the solution!

Comment: Glad you got the solution. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Just replace the follows code (here in 'aTargets' parameter we have to pass the columns index value which we want to disable sort function) in your jsfiddle code http://jsfiddle.net/koerner_klaus/csou71bn/5/

```
dataTable = $("#example").dataTable({
bDestroy: true,
bProcessing: false,
aaData: data,
orderable:false,
"aoColumnDefs" : [
 {
  'bSortable' : false,
  'aTargets' : [ 0, 1 ]
 }],
aoColumns: columns
```

});