# Proper function to re-initialize jquery datatables

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

In [SO: DataTables with different number of columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26480434/datatables-with-different-number-of-columns) the user asked for a solution to work with datatables.js and variable amount of columns. A working solution was provided here: http://jsfiddle.net/gss4a17t/.

This solution depends on a deprecated function:

```
    dataTable.fnDestroy(true);
```

Questions:

1. Why does the `destroy()` function not work here?
2. What is the difference between `$('table.dataTable').DataTable().destroy();` and `$('dataTable').DataTable().destroy();` in this situation?

i forked with the following jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Lx4mf1ht/7/

Answer (score 0):

1)
`destroy()` needs a DataTable object to work. It's a method of this kind of object. `fnDestroy()` is a method of a dataTable object.

**dataTable** is different object when compared to **DataTable** (check the captilized D). They have different methods and that's why `destroy()` should not work.

2)
`'table.dataTable'` is used as a jQuery  selector where it looks for a `<table>` element with a `dataTable` class which is OK

`'dataTable'` is a selector looking for a `<dataTable>` element I assume this one does not work since there is no such element.

Also, I am not sure what version of DataTables fiddle uses, but destroy() is there since v1.10

Comment: thanks, but my question 2. refers to "DataTable()" only. "dataTable()" is not mentioned here.